# is there a major inefficiency in this miller-rabin pseudocode in CLRS?

Tags: algorithm, primes, code-analysis, pseudocode, primality-test

This question may actually have nothing to do with the Miller-Rabin primality testing procedure; it may only easy analysis of some simple pseudocode.

On p 969 of CLRS (Introduction to Algorithms 3ed), an auxiliary function to Miller-Rabin is presented:

```
WITNESS(a, n)
    let t and u be such that t >= 1, u is odd, and n-1 = 2^t u
    x_0 = MODULAR-EXPONENTIATION(a, u, n)
    for i = 1 to t
        x_i = x_{i-1}^2 mod n
        if x_i == 1 and x_{i-1} != 1 and x_{i-1} != n-1
            return TRUE
    if x_t != 1
        return TRUE
    return FALSE
```

I copied the above exactly from the textbook.

Now, knowing only that `MODULAR-EXPONENTIATION` returns a result between 0 and n-1, inclusive, I think the pseudocode above is entirely equivalent to

```
WITNESS(a, n)
    let t and u be such that t >= 1, u is odd, and n-1 = 2^t u
    x_0 = MODULAR-EXPONENTIATION(a, u, n)
    if x_0 == 1 or x_0 == n-1
        return FALSE
    else
        return TRUE
```

If so, there's probably something else wrong with the original implementation, since if I'm not mistaken Miller-Rabin witnessing *does* require some sort of looping. Can someone provide a simple counterexample to show that I am wrong?

Comment: What does CLRS stand for?

Comment: updated, sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Miller-Rabin primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test#Concepts) is designed to be TRUE for n being a prime, so returning FALSE should only apply to composite numbers. Let's test this with a little Python program.

```
def wrongwitness(a, n):             #implementation of your shortcut
    u = n - 1
    t = 0
    while u % 2 == 0:               #n - 1 = 2^t * u
        u //= 2
        t += 1

    x_0 = pow(a, u, n)              #x0 = a ^ u (mod n), oops, where is t?

    if x_0 == 1 or x_0 == n - 1:
        return False
    else:
        return True

primes = [5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31]

for p in primes:         
    for a in range(2, p):           #1 < a < p
        if not wrongwitness(a, p):  #witness returned FALSE, though we have a prime number
            print("Found counter example: a = ", a, "and p = ", p )
```

This gives us lots of counterexamples for your shortcut implementation as small as `a = 2` and `p = 5` or `a = 3` and `p = 7`. Actually all `(p - 1, p)` tuples are counter examples. So no shortcut, you have to test all square roots of `a^(n-1)` as explained in your text book.

P.S.: But there are ways to reduce the number of calculations, you have to perform. [Subsets of witnesses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test#Deterministic_variants) have been identified for n up to 3,317,044,064,679,887,385,961,981. So for n < 1,373,653 it is for instance sufficient just to test a=2 and a=3.

Answer (score 0):

For the one in the book, we have `WITNESS(2, 5) == FALSE`

For the shortcut, we have `WITNESS(2, 5) == TRUE`, hence the shortcut is wrong.

By the way, the following alternative implementation *is* valid, and more efficiently terminates immediately in all cases when it finds `x_i == 1`.

```
WITNESS(a, n)
    let t and u be such that t >= 1, u is odd, and n-1 = 2^t u
    x_0 = MODULAR-EXPONENTIATION(a, u, n)
    for i = 1 to t
        x_i = x_{i-1}^2 mod n
        if x_i == 1 
            if x_{i-1} != 1 and x_{i-1} != n-1
                return TRUE
            else
                return FALSE
    return TRUE
```

Comment: Maybe of interest for you is this thread on [Maths SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4597/simple-explanation-and-examples-of-the-miller-rabin-primality-test#4598)